# Ubuntu won't boot after I used the command Killall -u

Tags: killall

I was downloading an apk and it told me I had to kill a process. I saw some posts on the kill command an thought I could kill the process like a pro, so I typed the following command:

```
kill all -u TAL
```

TAL is my only user

After that, I was logged out, I put my password, and it wouldn't log me in. I restarted the computer, and it didn't boot. It said:

```
end kernel panic- not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00007f00
```

Someone help please!

P.S. I dual boot Ubuntu with windows 10 on a lenovo think pad t420

Answer (score 1):

Just by the name, "kill all," you would know that it would kill all processes. When you entered the command, you must have killed some of the system process which might have caused an error. If you plan on "killing all" in the future, think. *'I should search how to kill one command and one only.'* You might have to reinstall Ubuntu, or boot Ubuntu into Recovery Mode (by holding the shift key) and resetting the settings to default (if you can).

Comment: Yeah I know, it was a stupid move. When do I hold shift?

Comment: @TAL you hold shift (on the right side of the keyboard) after pressing the power button to get the GRUB menu, then select Advanced Options for Ubuntu, then select the first kernel labelled Recovery.